# Is there any image converter through which I connect with java?

Tags: java, image-conversion

I asked one [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895654/unsupported-image-type-exception-in-only-few-images) here but I didn't get exactly what I wanted. So, now because of the unsupported image problem in ImageIO, I thought why don't I try another way to use it, by converting Unsupported images.

So, is there any open-source image converter in Java or is there any website or tool, through which I can connect with my Java application and then have that tool or website convert my jpg image to jpg or png image and then store that image in some place?

So that if an image is unsupported in ImageIO then I can store that image by converting it.

**This whole process should be done automatically, meaning the user should not have to open that website or tool and convert it manually.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php). It has a Java API - [JMagick](http://www.jmagick.org/index.html).

If the API doesn't suit you, you can, as a last resort, use ImageMagick as a command-line utility from java (by `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(..)`)

I don't know if it's suitable, but take a look at [JAI](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/) as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is also another API for ImageMagick, [im4java](http://im4java.sourceforge.net/).

JMagick is a thin JNI layer above the ImageMagick C-API. im4java in contrast just generates the commandline for the ImageMagick commands and passes the generated line to the selected IM-command (using the java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start()-method).