# Is there a 100% Java alternative to ImageIO for reading JPEG files?

Tags: java, jpeg, java-2d, javax.imageio, resize-image

We are using Java2D to resize photos uploaded to our website, but we run into an issue (a seemingly old one, cf.: http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5425569) - a few particular JPEGs raise a `CMMException` when we try to `ImageIO.read()` an InputStream containing their binary data:

```
java.awt.color.CMMException: Invalid image format
 at sun.awt.color.CMM.checkStatus(CMM.java:131)
 at sun.awt.color.ICC_Transform.<init>(ICC_Transform.java:89)
 at java.awt.image.ColorConvertOp.filter(ColorConvertOp.java:516)
 at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.acceptPixels(JPEGImageReader.java:1114)
 at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readImage(Native Method)
 at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readInternal(JPEGImageReader.java:1082)
 at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.read(JPEGImageReader.java:897)
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1422)
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1326)
    ...
```

(snipped the remainder of the stack trace, which is our `ImageIO.read()` call, servlet code and such)

We narrowed it down to photos taken on specific cameras, and I selected a photo that triggers this error: http://img214.imageshack.us/img214/5121/estacaosp.jpg. 
We noticed that this only happens with Sun's JVM (on Linux and Mac, just tested it on 1.6.0_20) - a test machine with OpenJDK reads the same photos without a hitch, possibly due to a different implementation of the JPEG reader.

Unfortunately, we are unable to switch JVMs in production, nor to use native-dependent solutions such as ImageMagick ( http://www.imagemagick.org/ ).

Considering that, my question is: Does a replacement for ImageIOs JPEG reader which can handle photos such as the linked one exist? If not, is there another 100% pure Java photo resizing solution which we can use?

Thank you!

Comment: By the way, I am aware that ImageIO does not process CMYK images (as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408613/problem-reading-jpeg-image-using-imageio-readfile-file). But the sample one is RGB (as far as Mac Preview is concerned, would be glad if someone could confirm that)

Comment: I opened a bug on the Oracle/Sun bug database here: 
http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7064516
Vote for it if you're still interested in the fix!

Comment: Note that this bug was marked as "Fixed in Java 8b56" in 2012.  So an alternative solution is to update to the latest Java 8 (or later).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One possibly useful library for you could be the Java Advanced Imaging Library ([JAI](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/iio-141084.html))

Using this library can be quite a bit more complicated than using ImageIO but in a quick test I just ran, it did open and display the problem image file you linked.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        RenderedImage image = JAI.create("fileload", "estacaosp.jpg");

        float scale=(float) 0.5;

        ParameterBlock pb = new ParameterBlock();
        pb.addSource(image);

        pb.add(scale);
        pb.add(scale);
        pb.add(1.0F);
        pb.add(1.0F);

        pb.add(new InterpolationNearest() );// ;InterpolationBilinear());
        image = JAI.create("scale", pb);

        // Create an instance of DisplayJAI.
        DisplayJAI srcdj = new DisplayJAI(image);

        JScrollPane srcScrollPaneImage = new JScrollPane(srcdj);

// Use a label to display the image
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        frame.getContentPane().add(srcScrollPaneImage, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

After running this code the image seems to load fine. It is then resized by 50% using the ParamaterBlock

And finally if you wish to save the file you can just call :

```
String filename2 = new String ("tofile.jpg");
  String format = new String ("JPEG");
  RenderedOp op = JAI.create ("filestore", image, filename2, format);
```

I hope this helps you out. Best of luck.

Comment: It sure does! Have to check out how well it will work on a "headless" setup, but I believe we can work it out. Thank you!

Comment: Just to let you know, our developers implemented this solution, and it worked like a charm. Again, thank you!

Comment: dead link, please update with http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/current-142188.html or whatever it is now.

Answer (score 10):

Old post, but for future reference:

Inspired by this question and links found here, I've written a JPEGImageReader plugin for ImageIO that supports JPEG images with these kind of "bad" ICC color profiles (the "issue" is the rendering intent in the ICC profile is incompatible with Java's ColorConvertOp). It's plain Java and does not require JAI.

The source code and linked binary builds are freely available from the [TwelveMonkeys project](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys#jpeg) on GitHub.

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same issue. I was reluctant to use JAI as it is outdated but it looks like it's the shortest solution.

This code converts an InputStream to a BufferedImage, using sun's ImageIO (fast) or in the few cases where this problem occur, using JAI:

```
public static BufferedImage read(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    try {
        // We try it with ImageIO
        return ImageIO.read(ImageIO.createImageInputStream(is));
    } catch (CMMException ex) {
        // If we failed...
        // We reset the inputStream (start from the beginning)
        is.reset();
        // And use JAI
        return JAI.create("stream", SeekableStream.wrapInputStream(is, true)).getAsBufferedImage();
    }
}
```