# Detecting image encoding in Java

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I'm accepting an image as input from the user. I want to only allow a JPEG image. The image is arriving as an InputStream (called `myInputStream` below). In the code below, the Iterator returned by `ImageIO.getImageReaders()` is always empty.

```
ImageInputStream imageInputStream = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(
    myInputStream);
Iterator<ImageReader> iter = ImageIO.getImageReaders(imageInputStream);
if (!iter.hasNext()) {
    // this always happens
}
ImageReader reader = (ImageReader) iter.next();
if (!reader.getFormatName().equals("jpeg")) {
    // haven't got this far yet
}
```

I have also tried passing `myInputStream` directly to `ImageIO.getImageReaders()` with the same result.

Comment: write you OS and JDK versions. On my ubuntu 10.04 with OpenJDK 6, `ImageIO.getImageReaders` returns an instance of `com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader`

Comment: It's Mac OS X 10.6 with JDK 1.6 (the default version that comes with OS X)

Comment: seems like mac osx does not support advanced java imaging http://forums.java.net/node/669174

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An empty iterator usually means ImageIO hasn't found a good image reader for decoding your image. This may be because you'are missing the [right decoder in your classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047667/problem-using-imageio-read), or you image has an [unsupported color model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408613/problem-reading-jpeg-image-using-imageio-readfile-file).