# ImageIO : cannot read image with CMYK color space

Tags: java, javax.imageio, jai

I have a problem to read a specific jpeg image (CMYK color space) which have been created with ImageMagick :

```
inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytesImage);
bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(inputStream); 
//IIOException : unsupported image type
```

I tried to use JAI instead of ImageIO but it still doesn't work :

```
seekableStream = new ByteArraySeekableStream(bytesImage);
bufferedImage = JAI.create("Stream", seekableStream).getAsBufferedImage();
//Unable to render RenderedOp for this operation
```

Any idea to solve my problem?

Comment: Is the data of this file stored on disk where this program can read it?

Comment: Yes and the inputSteam is correctly filled.

Comment: @FranckJS: I don't know whether this is still relevant for you but I've posted an answer that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Reading JPEG images with CMYK colors is rather tricky in Java. But I've posted a complete solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12132556/413337). It solves the problem of dark colors becoming white as well.

Answer (score 2):

Since I have found my image has a CMYK color space, I have found a solution on stackoverflow : [Problem reading jpeg image using imageio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408613/problem-reading-jpeg-image-using-imageio-readfile-file)

Now, the problem is the quality of my resulting image... dark colors became white...