# CMYK Image display on pdf using pdfbox

Tags: java, spring-mvc, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I am trying to create pdf in java using pdfbox 1.8, but problem is I am not able to show CMYK image on pdf so I try to solution on same like below code:

```
File filePath = new File("C:/Users/msuryawanshi/Documents/10734730431625_C1LA.jpg");
JPEGImageDecoder jpegDecoder = JPEGCodec.createJPEGDecoder(new FileInputStream(filePath));
BufferedImage image = jpegDecoder.decodeAsBufferedImage();
imageUrl = "http://extranet.handgards.com/gs1/10734730431625_C1LA.jpg";
File f = new File("C:/Users/msuryawanshi/Documents/10734730431625_C1LA.jpg");
String url = "http://extranet.handgards.com/gs1/10734730431625_C1LA.jpg";
Iterator readers = ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("JPEG");
ImageReader reader = null;
while (readers.hasNext()) {
    reader = (ImageReader) readers.next();
    if (reader.canReadRaster()) {
        break;
    }
}

//Stream the image file (the original CMYK image)
ImageInputStream input = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(f);
reader.setInput(input);
//Read the image raster
Raster raster = reader.readRaster(0, null);

//Create a new RGB image
BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(raster.getWidth(), raster.getHeight(),
        BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
//Fill the new image with the old raster
bi.getRaster().setRect(raster);
PDXObjectImage ximage = new PDPixelMap(document, bi);
contentStream.drawXObject(ximage, margin + 5, texty, 170, 100);
```

[image]

but image is not meaningful, I have attached output pdf and original image which i want display on my pdf. please help for the same.

Comment: I'm not able to understand from your question if you want to embed the CMYK version of the JPEG or not, either way - handling CMYK jpegs in Java is tricky. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118712/java-cmyk-to-rgb-with-profile-output-is-too-dark/12132556#12132556 for a possible solution

Comment: PDFBox doesn't support embedding CMYK images at all. You might be able to embed it as an RGB image by using the twelvemonkeys library https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/ instead of Java ImageIO.

Comment: Hi @iddo i was try that solution but i am getting error atJpegImageParser parser = new JpegImageParser();( JpegImageParser cannot be resolved to a type )ByteSource byteSource = new ByteSourceFile(file);ByteSource cannot be resolved to a type, is there any jar needed?

Comment: @Tilman probably you should post that as an answer. Even if it is negative. After all, no positive answer is to be expected.

Comment: @Manojkumar you should contact the original post author about that

Answer (score 1):

PDFBox doesn't support embedding CMYK images at all because java itself can't read such images. You might be able to embed it as an RGB image by using the [twelvemonkeys library](http://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys) instead of Java ImageIO to read the JPEG into a BufferedImage. From there, just use PDPixelMap (in 1.8) or LosslessFactory (in 2.0).