# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/image/codec/jpeg/JPEGCodec

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

So I'm working on a java-made plugin of the well known **Cooja Simulator**..when I click on a button, I get the exception you see in the title..
I've already read many posts related to the same issue and I have put the issuing classes in the classpath environment var, in this way (I'm working on Ubuntu):

The classes contained in **"com/sun/image/codec/jpeg/JPEGCodec"** are located here:

**"/home/user/contiki-2.6/jar_files/lib"**, so that the full path is **"/home/user/contiki-2.6/jar_files/lib/com/sun/image/codec/jpeg/JPEGCodec"**.

I've edited the bashrc file and I've inserted the following line:

**export CLASSPATH=.:/path1:/path2:/path3:/home/user/contiki-2.6/jar_files/lib**

Where the latter one is the path where my problematic classes are located..in the source code, the classes are imported in this way:

```
import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGImageEncoder;  
import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGCodec;  
import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGEncodeParam;
```

And I make the Cooja Simulator starts using the command:
**ant run**

I've also tried to force the required jar/classes by issuing:

**ant -lib /home/user/contiki-2.6/jar_files/lib/com/sun/image/codec/jpeg run_bigmem**

but I got the same error..  Anyone who can help me to solve this issue? thanks a lot..

Comment: Are the classes located in a JAR ? If so, add the JAR explicitly in your classpath.

Comment: Take a look here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8015291/how-to-replace-com-sun-image-codec-jpeg-jpegimageencoder-in-this-code

Comment: @Stephan by adding something like:  
export CLASSPATH=.:/path1:/path2:/path3:/home/user/contiki-2.6/jar_files/lib/rt.jar  
in the bashrc file?

Comment: What's the name of your jar file?

Comment: @VishalK the name is rt.jar, I've extracted all the libraries' folder and add that path in the CLASSPATH env-var

Comment: If you have all classes in `rt.jar` then better copy that jar file in lib folder and use this as classpath: `export CLASSPATH=.:/path1:/path2:/path3:/home/user/contiki-2.6/jar_files/lib/rt.jar`

Comment: @VishalK it is what I did, now my CLASSPATH lokks this way:  
export CLASSPATH=.:/path1:/path2:/path3:/home/user/contiki-2.6/jar_files/lib:/home/user/contiki-2.6/jar_files/lib/rt.jar  

I included the *.jar and also the un-packed libraries folder, but with no luck..

Comment: Can you do one thing for testing purpose? just put `rt.jar` in the folder from where you are running `ant` command. and while executing `ant` use following `ant -lib rt.jar`

Comment: I'm getting the same error..

Answer (score 1):

Cooja has its own classloader. To add additional jars add a `lib`-folder to your plugin and copy the jars into that folder. Then add

se.sics.cooja.GUI.JARFILES = + file1.jar file2.jar

to the `cooja.config`.
Look at https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/tree/master/tools/cooja/apps/mspsim as an example - here the required jars are copied by Ant.