# Generate Image by Servlet

Tags: java, servlets

This is my first servlet to generate and display image to the client,

But There is compile time error in the mentioned section by commect.

```
public class DynamicImage extends HttpServlet {

@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

    response.setContentType("image/jpeg");

    //create image
    int width = 200;
    int height = 30;
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    //get drawing context
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

    //draw a string
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    g.drawString("My String!", 10, height / 2 + 4);

    //draw a border
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawRect(0, 0, width - 1, height - 1);

    //dispose context
    g.dispose();

    //send back image to the client
    ServletOutputStream sos = response.getOutputStream();
    com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGImageEncoder encoder = JPEGCodec // Compile Time Error, cant find JPEGCodec

    }
}
```

My IDE (Netbeans) cant find and import `JPEGCodec` , What is the solution?

Comment: classes from the com.sun package are not documented, and not supposed to be used. Use a public API that can write images in JPEG, like ImageIO.

Comment: Highly advise against generating images in servlets. The image should already exist on the file system or in a database; not only is it inefficient to do this in the servlet, but some servers do not have graphics cards or a GraphicsEnvironment, so your graphics operations may fail.

Comment: @ControlAltDel I can think of quite a few use cases for generating images server side. Producing images server-side isn't unusual at all. To handle not have a graphics system just set the property for headless mode: -Djava.awt.headless=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are needed to download **rt.jar** file and add it in your class path.
Download it from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/java-rt/java-rt-jar-stubs-1.5.0.jar.zip).
*If above link does not work visit [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavartjarstubs150jar.htm)*

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8015291/how-to-replace-com-sun-image-codec-jpeg-jpegimageencoder-in-this-code)

I would recommend not to use this class. It's nothing but headache.