# In a java program (using NetBeans) how could captured from WebCam and save it in a standard format?

Tags: java, image, webcam-capture

In a java program (using NetBeans) how could one without using the sun package ​package com.sun.image.codec.jpeg, save the image resulted from the lti-civil library captured from WebCam?

In order to convert into jar-file , we faced this error:

error: package com.sun.image.codec.jpeg does not exist

import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGCodec

How can I solve this problem please? Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8015410/995891