# ColdFusion IsImageFile fails for jpg file

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

2 jpg images that look exactly the same (failing image above, no.jpg, resaved as yes.png) but one is not an Image according to IsImageFile function.

Run this code

```
#IsImageFile("http://fdiapp.com/ini/cms/file_uploads/yes.jpg")#
**
#IsImageFile("http://fdiapp.com/ini/cms/file_uploads/no.jpg")#
```

Comment: I cannot check right now, but any chance the jpg is of the (problematic) `CMYK` variety?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that is a `CMYK` jpeg. ColdFusion 9 uses `ImageIO` internally, which afaik [only supports RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408613/problem-reading-jpeg-image-using-imageio-readfile-file). (While some of the java suggestions in that thread do work from ColdFusion - the colors in the resulting image are skewed.) What is probably happening is that `ImageIO` fails to even load the image file and that is why `IsImageFile` returns "no".

FWIW, `IsImageFile` returns "yes" in ColdFusion 10. However, it still has issues with `CMYK`. For example if you try and read the image, the final colors are all wrong ...

I think your best bet is to run it through a tool like [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) and convert it to a format ColdFusion can handle properly.