# jpeg image color gets drastically changed after just ImageIO.read() and ImageIO.write()

Tags: java, image, image-processing

I have been using ImageIO.read() and ImageIO.write() methods in javax.imageio.ImageIO for reading and writing images, and I found that some images' color gets changed weirdly.

Even if I change my code to do nothing but just read images and write them (with jpeg, png, gif), all those new images have the same issue.

Do I need to add any other code before/after ImageIO.read/write methods?

Here is the code I used:

```
    File f = new File("obw.jpg");
    BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(f);
    FileOutputStream fos2 = new FileOutputStream("obw2.jpg");
    ImageIO.write(bi, "JPG", fos2);
    FileOutputStream fos3 = new FileOutputStream("obw3.gif");
    ImageIO.write(bi, "GIF", fos3);
    FileOutputStream fos4 = new FileOutputStream("obw4.png");
    ImageIO.write(bi, "PNG", fos4);
```

My environment:

```
    java version "1.6.0_35"
    MacOSX 10.8.2
```

Original Image:
[image]

One of images after read and write:

[image]

Comment: Which one gets changed, or all of them? is the original image maybe *corrupt*?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408613/problem-reading-jpeg-image-using-imageio-readfile-file

Comment: I read the original image and wrote jpeg, png, gif images and all of three show that green obiwan... is there any way i can check if that original image is corrupt?

Comment: lesto, I tried using raster(with JPEGImageReader, not the Sanselan library), but that code gives the ArrayOutOfBoundsException, which is not the behavior happening when reading CMYK image..

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your problem is that ImageIO is misinterpreting the YCbCr data in your JPEG as RBG data. The relevant Java bugs are [4712797](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4712797) and [4776576](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4776576), which Oracle wrongly claims were fixed in Java 1.4, but in reality still afflict some Java 5, 6, and 7 JVMs.

In a project I work on, we've dealt with this problem by loading a specially-constructed [test JPEG with a single black pixel](https://sourceforge.net/p/vassalengine/svn/HEAD/tree/VASSAL-src/trunk/src/images/black.jpg) to see if ImageIO loads it properly. If the pixel comes up green, then ImageIO is misinterpreting the image data, so when we load JPEGs later and we detect the sort of JPEG which causes the problem, we also apply a color correction. (The kind of JPEG which triggers the problem in JVMs which exhibit it has a particular kind of subsampling and no JFIF marker.)

Here's some [LGPLv2-licensed code](https://sourceforge.net/p/vassalengine/svn/HEAD/tree/VASSAL-src/trunk/src/VASSAL/tools/image/ImageIOImageLoader.java) which deals with the problem. The need for code like this to work around dozen-year-old bugs when the whole rest of the world manages to load JPEGs properly is one of the reasons I want Java to die in a fire.

Comment: Thank you!! I feel much safer now!!

Comment: Still not fixed - I'm seeing this problem on Java 8.

Answer (score 2):

seems a colorspace problem, imageIO try to do some encoding/decoding of the image but it seems to fail. Take a look here:
[Unable to read JPEG image using ImageIO.read(File file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408613/problem-reading-jpeg-image-using-imageio-readfile-file)