# Colors appear wrong in image file if image type is TYPE_INT_ARGB and writing with ImageIO

Tags: java, graphics, javax.imageio

The code below creates apparently wrong image file.

It appears as

[image]

while it should be

[image]

or something. Anyway, circle should be yellow.

How to fix?

The code is below

```
package tests.org.piccolo2d;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

import org.piccolo2d.nodes.PPath;

public class Try_SaveImage {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        /*
        PPath path = PPath.createEllipse(0, 0, 100, 100);
        path.setPaint(new Color(0xECB77E));
        path.setStrokePaint(Color.black);

        BufferedImage image = (BufferedImage) path.toImage();
        */
        //BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB); // works good
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB); // works bad
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
        g2.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g2.fillOval(0, 0, 100, 100);
        g2.setColor(Color.black);
        g2.drawOval(0, 0, 100, 100);


        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image)), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setVisible(true);

        ImageIO.write(image, "JPG", new File("testdata/circle.jpg"));

    }

}
```

Comment: Thats a strange one alight, you could try to save it as a PNG that works ok.

Comment: PNG works bad if read back

Comment: Why do you want to write `TYPE_INT_ARGB` as JPEG? JPEG doesn't (in a good way) support alpha, so it kind of makes no sense (although what you are seeing here is most likely a bug). Either use `TYPE_INT_RGB` and JPEG, or `TYPE_INT_ARGB` and TIFF or PNG (PNG should work, if not update with evidence or create a new question :-) ).

Comment: PS: Just ran your code (in Oracle JRE 1.7.0_45) and observed: a) Java can read the image back, and shows it just the same as before it was written. b) Windows shows the image as in your screen shot (ie. magenta, instead of yellow).

Answer (score 2):

I had pretty much the same problem. Unexpected colors. Doing as haraldK suggests above fixed the issue for me. Use TYPE_INT_RGB not TYPE_INT_ARGB.

This produced the expected black line on a white background whereas using TYPE_INT_ARGB did not

```
BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics2D g2d = bi.createGraphics();
g2d.setPaint(Color.WHITE);
g2d.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
g2d.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
g2d.drawLine(0, 0, 200, 200);
ImageIO.write(bi, "JPEG", new File("c:\\temp\\TestImage.JPG"));
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it is a know bug in ImageIO

have a look at [ [jpeg image color gets drastically changed after just ImageIO.read() and ImageIO.write()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13072312/jpeg-image-color-gets-drastically-changed-after-just-imageio-read-and-imageio) ]