# While using java.awt.image.BufferedImage getSubimage() method to get subimage, the color of subimage is wrong

Tags: java, image

While using java.awt.image.BufferedImage getSubimage() method 
`BufferedImage outImage = bufferedImage.getSubimage(x, y, width, height);` to get subimage, the color of subimage is wrong.
[image]

How can i get the correct color image in java?

[image: test image]

P.S. after uploading the image to imgur and using the image downloaded from url, I found the color of subimage right...please use this image http://img01.taobaocdn.com/tfscom/LB17L9HKXXXXXbhXXXXSutbFXXX

Comment: You're saving the subimage as JPEG, but the subimage has a alpha channel...

Comment: I see the property of the source file, the property alpha channel is false...

Comment: Which is basically described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13072312/jpeg-image-color-gets-drastically-changed-after-just-imageio-read-and-imageio). The "basic" solution is to create a `BufferedImage` of `TYPE_RGB` and paint the subimage to it, then you can the new (non alpha based) image

Comment: I didn't say the "source", I said the "subimage".  Save it as a PNG, see if you get the same problem.  `ImageIO` doesn't support alpha channels in JPEGs :P

Comment: Can you provide a a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses.  I tried with your original image and have no issue

Comment: After i upload this source image and download it from imgur, the image is changed by imgur and have no issue...

Comment: http://img01.taobaocdn.com/tfscom/LB17L9HKXXXXXbhXXXXSutbFXXX   @MadProgrammer you can use this image

Comment: Okay, I can at least read the image now :P - It might be a CMYK issue, see [this Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408613/unable-to-read-jpeg-image-using-imageio-readfile-file) for some more details. Most the solutions require some third party library/plugin, for [example](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys)