# BufferedImage doesn't change color - Java

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I am trying to create a 1920x1080 colored image with Java, but for some reason I can't change the color. All I get is black, whatever values I place in color RGB. Here is the code:

```
BufferedImage background = new BufferedImage(1920,1080,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g = background.createGraphics();
g.setPaint ( new Color ( 100, 100, 250 ) );
g.fillRect ( 0, 0, background.getWidth(), background.getHeight() );
g.dispose();

try {
    ImageIO.write(background, "jpg", new File("output.jpg"));
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code works fine for me and prints out a nice gray-green filled image.

Comment: Not to me as your code looks fine to me. Are you sure that you're looking at the right `output.jpg` file?

Comment: Yes, I check the right one

Comment: When I run this code on my MacBook, and I open with Preview, I see a black rectangle. When I open it with Chrome, it's green.

Comment: And.. when I change the image type to TYPE_INT_RGB, the image is blue in both Preview and Chrome. Which makes sense because the color is `100,100,250` which is blue. A clear hint is the color space: when using type TYPE_INT_ARGB, the colorspace is in CMYK. When using TYPE_INT_RGB, the colorspace is RGB. CMYK color space is probably handled incorrectly by viewers.

Comment: (The colorspace is the one I see in the MacOS finder - it shouldn't be CMYK but it is. Strange. Could be a bug in the Java 8 ImageIO class, or in the MacOS finder)

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Unfortunately, JPEG doesn't have a way of defining color space. Instead it's interpreted from multiple fields (typically JFIF, Exif and Adobe app markers + inspecting the component ids), by [convention](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/metadata/doc-files/jpeg_metadata.html#color) (oh, and the algorithm described in that document is wrong... ;-) ).

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer. I changed the:

```
BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB
```

to:

```
BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB
```

and it worked. Weird though.

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: May be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13072312/jpeg-image-color-gets-drastically-changed-after-just-imageio-read-and-imageio (although this talks about reading, not writing, but it seems to be related)