# Need help to remove exception in my java graphics code

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

I am developing an application in swing which has 5 tabs with following 5 operations on an image :No Operation ,Color Convert ,Affine Transform ,Convolve and Look Up.

Here is the code :

```
import java.awt.color.ColorSpace;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.AffineTransformOp;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.ColorConvertOp;
import java.awt.image.ConvolveOp;
import java.awt.image.Kernel;
import java.awt.image.LookupOp;
import java.awt.image.LookupTable;
import java.awt.image.ShortLookupTable;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;


public class ImageProcessing extends JFrame{
BufferedImage source;
public static void main(String args[])
{
    try {
         UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
    } catch (Exception e1){e1.printStackTrace();}
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){public void run(){new ImageProcessing();}});
}

public ImageProcessing() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super("Image Processing");
    setSize(600,400);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    try
    {
        source=ImageIO.read(new File("src/abc.jpg"));
    }catch(IOException e){System.out.println("Exception Here :"+e);}

    JTabbedPane jtp=new JTabbedPane();
    buildNoOpTab(jtp);
    buildAffineTransformOpTab(jtp);
    buildColorConvertOpTab(jtp);
    buildConvolveOpTab(jtp);
    buildLookUpOpTab(jtp);
    //buildRescaleOpTab(jtp);

    add(jtp);
    setVisible(true);

}
private void buildNoOpTab(JTabbedPane jtp)
{
    jtp.add("No Op",new JLabel(new ImageIcon(source)));
}
private void buildAffineTransformOpTab(JTabbedPane jtp)
{
    BufferedImage dst;
    AffineTransform transform=AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(0.5, 0.5);
    AffineTransformOp op=new AffineTransformOp(transform, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
    dst=op.filter(source, null);
    jtp.add("AffineTransform",new JLabel(new ImageIcon(dst)));
}
private void buildColorConvertOpTab(JTabbedPane jtp)
{
    BufferedImage dst = null;
    ColorSpace clr=ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_GRAY);
    ColorConvertOp op=new ColorConvertOp(clr,null);
    dst=op.filter(source,dst);
    jtp.add("Color Convert",new JLabel(new ImageIcon(dst)));
}
 private void buildConvolveOpTab(JTabbedPane jtp) {
        BufferedImage dst = null;
        float sharpen[] = new float[] {
             0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,
            -1.0f,  5.0f, -1.0f,
             0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f
        };
        Kernel kernel = new Kernel(3, 3, sharpen);
        ConvolveOp op = new ConvolveOp(kernel);
        dst = op.filter(source, null);

        jtp.add("Convolve", new JLabel(new ImageIcon(dst)));
    }
 private void buildLookUpOpTab(JTabbedPane jtp)
 {
     BufferedImage dst=null;
     short[] data=new short[256];
     for(int i=0;i<256;i++)
         data[i]=(short)(255-i);
     LookupTable lkp=new ShortLookupTable(0,data);
     LookupOp op=new LookupOp(lkp,null);
     dst=op.filter(source, null);
     jtp.add("Look Up",new JLabel(new ImageIcon(dst)));
}


}
```

There is some problem in the buildLookUpOpTab as removing this method application works fine.

Here is the exception which I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
  Number of color/alpha components should be 3 but length of bits array is 1
  at java.awt.image.ColorModel.<init>(ColorModel.java:336)
  at java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel.<init>(ComponentColorModel.java:273)
  at java.awt.image.LookupOp.createCompatibleDestImage(LookupOp.java:413)
  at java.awt.image.LookupOp.filter(LookupOp.java:153)
  at ImageProcessing.buildLookUpOpTab(ImageProcessing.java:108)
  at ImageProcessing.<init>(ImageProcessing.java:49)
  at ImageProcessing$1.run(ImageProcessing.java:30)
  at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
  at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:701)
  at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:102)
  at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:662)
  at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:660)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
  at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:671)
  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
```

Can anyone tell me what is the problem in that method?

Comment: Which line of code throws this exception? In other words, which line is ImageProcessing.java:108?

Comment: ImageProcessing is my Class name .And actually there is no such line number 108.My full code is 102 lines long.

Comment: Your exception states different. It tells  you that this line: `ImageProcessing.buildLookUpOpTab(ImageProcessing.java:108)`, line 108 of the ImageProcessing.java class is where the exception is thrown. Please try to re-run your code to see if the line number has changed. If not, then get a decent text editor program and try to find line 108 for us.

Comment: It's likely this line: `dst=op.filter(source, null);`. Please look up the API for this as it will tell you *exactly* when this exception is thrown and why.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels :You said it right. Running again 108 changed to 97 and that line is 
''''dst=op.filter(source, null);''''

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels :The API says the following about filter()

    Throws:
    IllegalArgumentException - if the number of arrays in the LookupTable does not meet the restrictions described in the class comments, or if the source image has an IndexColorModel.

    But i don't understand what it is saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove alpha channel from your image before using any filter on it. To make your code working, change:

```
try
    {
        source=ImageIO.read(new File("src/abc.jpg"));
    } catch(IOException e){System.out.println("Exception Here :"+e);}
```

with this:

```
 try
    {
        BufferedImage src = ImageIO.read(new File("abc.jpg"));
        int w = src.getWidth();
        int h = src.getHeight();
        source = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Raster raster = src.getRaster().createChild(0, 0, w, h, 0, 0, 
            new int[] {0, 1, 2});
        source.setData(raster);
    }catch(IOException e){System.out.println("Exception Here :"+e);}
```

The above code creates a new buffered image in `RGB` mode and set the `RGB` data of original image to new buffered image ignoring the `alpha` values. But in case your original image contains completely transparent spots then it will become black spots in new buffered image.

Answer (score 5):

The `LookupOp.filter` method says that:

*Performs a lookup operation on a BufferedImage. If the color model in the source image is not the same as that in the destination image, the pixels will be converted in the destination. If the destination image is null, a BufferedImage will be created with an appropriate ColorModel. **An IllegalArgumentException might be thrown if the number of arrays in the LookupTable does not meet the restrictions stated in the class comment above, or if the source image has an IndexColorModel.***

Since you are filtering a `BufferedImage` created from using `ImageIO.read`, the color model that the image will have will definitely not be IndexColorModel, since `JPEGImageReader` (which actually created the BufferdImage from the file) does not support `IndexColorModel` - in the olden days, JPEGs used the `DirectColorModel`

Have a look at the answer on this thread on how to read a JPEG file and use a different color model:
[Unable to read JPEG image using ImageIO.read(File file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408613/problem-reading-jpeg-image-using-imageio-readfile-file)

Comment: So what can i do to obtain Index color model??

Comment: @Naveen Have a read of the answer on the thread I posted in my answer.